# GRUB doesn't see ext4 partitions (error: no such partition)

Tags: partition, grub

I have strange trouble with Linux Mint 13 installation. I have Windows XP installed, I want to install Linux Mint as a second system (with dual boot), I've already done it multiple times on several machines, with exactly the same Mint version and even exactly the same installation media. But this time, I'm running into troubles: just after new Linux Mint installation is complete, I reboot, and I see the following:

```
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

I googled much and tried all of this: http://itsfoss.com/solve-error-partition-grub-rescue-ubuntu-linux/ and similar howto-s, nothing helped. I.e. I've reinstalled grub, no errors reported, but when I reboot, I got the same error again.

But then, I've noticed strange fact. I have two NTFS partitions: `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5`. My main Linux partition is on `/dev/sda6`, swap is `/dev/sda7`.

Then, in grub rescue prompt, I've entered `ls`, and the output is:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
```

But, all of these partitions are actually NTFS! So that it doesn't see my `ext4` partition completely. That's why it says "no such partition". Note that if I load via livecd and gun gparted, I see all of these partitions, everything looks fine. Of course I can mount it somewhere and `chroot` into it, it works.

But, GRUB doesn't see them.

What could be the trouble, and how to fix it?

**UPD:**

output of `sfdisk -d /dev/sda`:

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
# partition table of /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=       63, size=102392577, Id= 7, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=102392701, size=522749059, Id= 5
/dev/sda3 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda4 : start=        0, size=        0, Id= 0
/dev/sda5 : start=102392703, size=324082017, Id= 7
/dev/sda6 : start=426475520, size=194473984, Id=83
/dev/sda7 : start=620951552, size=  4190208, Id=82
```

I'm not sure what exactly does that warning mean, but note that on another machine with the same configuration (WinXP + Linux Mint) I have very similar output of `sfdisk`, so that it shouldn't be a problem.

**UPD2:**

As @AvinashRaj suggested, I tried boot-repair, but it didn't help. Log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7209498/

(it seems there was some problems, but at the end it reported `Boot successfully repaired.`)

And let me repeat that the GRUB just doesn't see my linux partitions (`sda6` and `sda7`), for some reason.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7209498/

Comment: What is the output of `sfdisk -d /dev/sda`?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: What's the status of all these partitions? Are you using them all? It would seem like the bootloader is "confused" and doesn't know which device to use to boot.

Comment: Try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).If the problem not yet solved then post the contents of boot-repair log in your question.

Comment: @slm Is that relevant for `ls`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - not nec. but it would seem as though GRUB doesn't know which partition to use.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't help. I updated my question, please see **UPD2**.

Comment: Do you have GPT? If you does, it may cause errors, because of not having grub boot partition.

Comment: @enedil, no I haven't (I have MBR, if I understood you correctly)

Comment: How new is your disk? Most of hard drives released after 2001 have 4kb block size instead of 512b. I had an issue about 4 months ago.

Comment: @enedil, is there a way to check block size with some utility? It's a notebook (as well as other computers which work correctly with WinXP and Linux Mint), and I'm not sure when it was made, I've bought it not brand new.

Comment: I have the same issue please help!

Comment: @Berke, have you read my answer below? Just try to create `/boot` partition **at the beginning of HDD**, and try to reinstall system using it. For myself, I've allocated 500MB for it just in case, but people around say that 200MB should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the problem was that my HDD is too large for the BIOS in my laptop (320 GB), laptop is HP Compaq nw8240.

Firstly, I tried to completely reformat my HDD with `gparted`: I've created similar partition structure, installed Linux, GRUB doesn't work again, but now I got different error message: `Error: out of disk`.

After some googling I found that large HDD might cause this, so I've created little partition for `/boot` in the beginning of the HDD, reinstalled system using this partition, and now it works.